# Serilog Json configuration to API: filters

Tags: c#, serilog

I need to log to different sinks depending on the value of a property named "EventType".
I figured out something in JSON configuration but I can't seem to understand how to translate to code (I need to have the same logging strategy hard coded).

I read the documentation about [Expressions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions) but can't seem to make it work.

Here is an extract of the JSON config:

```json
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/SystemLog.txt",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 31,
                  "buffered": false,
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Properties} {Message:lj} {NewLine}{Exception}",
                  "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "EventType = 'System'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
          }
        }
 ]
}
```

And here is what I tried in code:

```cs
loggerConfiguration
    .WriteTo.Logger(configureLogger: conf => {
            conf.WriteTo.File(path: "Logs/SystemLog.txt",
                outputTemplate:
                "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Properties} {Message:lj} {NewLine}{Exception}",
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                retainedFileCountLimit: 31,
                buffered: false,
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug);
            conf.Filter.ByIncludingOnly( expression: "UserEvent = 'System'");
            conf.Enrich.FromLogContext();
    });
```

I also tried to change the Filter to `conf.Filter.ByIncludingOnly( expression: "@p['UserEvent'] = 'System'");`

But still no log...
I would appreciate if you could guide me towards the proper syntax.
Thank you for your help.

**SOLUTION:**

Chinmay T posted a working solution below, but I wanted to share what I ended up doing. I'm using a `Conditional` and check that the property is existing:

```cs
.WriteTo.Conditional(
    evt => evt.Properties.ContainsKey("EventType") &&
           evt.Properties["EventType"].ToString().Replace("\"", "") == "System",
    wt =>
        wt.File("Logs/SystemLog.txt",
            outputTemplate:outputTemplate,
            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
            retainedFileCountLimit: 31,
            buffered: false,
            restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug)
)
```

My issue was that the property's value had extra quotation added to the value...

Although, I would say that the added benefit of using `WriteTo.Logger` (like my first attempt and Chinmay T suggestion, is that you have more configuration options over the logger rather than the sink. It may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Console App project template as an example here with .Net7 as target framework. Below source code is available [here](https://github.com/chinmay-trivedi/SeriLogExamples)

> Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Debugging;
using Serilog.Events;
using System.Diagnostics;

 var configFile = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                //.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())                
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configFile)
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
                .Filter.ByExcluding(l => l.Level == LogEventLevel.Information || l.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug || l.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning || l.Properties["EventType"].Equals("System"))
                .WriteTo.File(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName + @"\\Logs\\log-Information-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
            .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
                .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(l => l.Level == LogEventLevel.Error || l.Level == LogEventLevel.Fatal)
                .WriteTo.File(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName + @"\\Logs\\log-Error-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
            .CreateLogger();

SelfLog.Enable(Console.Out);

try
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    Serilog.Log.Logger.Information("*************************** Read DailyFile Started *****************************");

    for (global::System.Int32 i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);

        if (i==50)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i--);
            Serilog.Log.Error("File Watcher Error on {2} --- {0} {EventType} for file type {1} deactivated...", sw.Elapsed, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, i, "System");
        }

    }

    Console.ReadKey();

    sw.Stop();
    Serilog.Log.Logger.Information("File Watcher on {0} for file type {1} deactivated...", sw.Elapsed, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Serilog.Log.Logger.Information("*************************** Read DailyFile Completed *****************************");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "File Watcher failed with {err}...", ex.InnerException);
    throw;
}
finally
{
    Log.Information("File Watcher stopped...");
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

> Appsettings.json config

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" , "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Enrichers.Environment", "Serilog.Enrichers.Thread", "Serilog.Exceptions", "Serilog.Expressions" ],
  "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Console"     
    },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "Logs/SystemLog.txt",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "retainedFileCountLimit": 31,
        "buffered": false,
        "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Properties} {Message:lj} {NewLine}{Exception}",
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug"
      }
      
    ]}
```

> It is logging data into separate files based on log filter express

[image]

Logfile contents

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed suggestion. In the meantime I came up with an alternate solution using a Conditional but I think your suggestion, using WriteTo.Logger is superior ;)

Comment: I'm glad that my answer helps you to find your way !! Happy coding :)